# Discordant optimal total cholesterol levels for lowest mortality?

Tags: epidemiology, cardiovascular-disease, cholesterol, mortality-rate

The 2019 ESC/EAS dyslipidemia guidelines [1] recommend lowering LDL cholesterol as much as possible to reduce cardiovascular risk. They cite evidence that higher LDL cholesterol increases CVD risk and state there is no known unsafe lower limit.

However, a 2019 Korean cohort study [2] found a U-shaped association between total cholesterol (TC) and mortality. Optimal TC ranges for lowest mortality were 210-249 mg/dL for most groups, with increased mortality below 200 mg/dL.

These findings seem conflicting - one advocates lowering cholesterol as much as possible, while the other suggests TC <200 mg/dL may increase mortality. What factors could account for these disparate optimal TC ranges for lowest all-cause mortality?

References:

[1] Mach F et al. 2019 ESC/EAS dyslipidemia guidelines. Eur Heart J. 2020;41(1):111-188.

[2] Yi SW et al. Total cholesterol and all-cause mortality by sex and age. Sci Rep. 2019;9(1):1596.

Comment: You're conflating two things LDL and total cholesterol, which is LDL+HDL.